# What happens when adding '++' before array in C++?

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code:

```
for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
   double number=distribution(generator);
    ++p[int(nintervals*number)];
}
```

but I dont know how ++ affects the array.Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Your code ends up behind the [door on the right](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m).

Comment: @HansPassant Well, `++array[index]` is not quite WTF. If one doesn't realize what that is doing, then he clearly has no idea about basic C++ syntax. (Which explains my surprise about this question having gotten an upvote.)

Comment: Actually, the program is not C, so I removed the C tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`++` is simply an operator and will operate on an array *element* in your example.

So these three lines are equivalent:

```
p[int(nintervals*number)]++;
p[int(nintervals*number)] += 1;
p[int(nintervals*number)] = p[int(nintervals*number)] + 1;
```

So the `++` operator does not operate on the *array*; it operates on the *element* of the array you have indexed.  I hope this is clear.

NOW, if you bound the `++` operator to the *array* as in the following example, then the resulting action is quite different.

```
(++p)[int(nintervals*number)];
```

This will increment the pointer `p` and then index into the memory that (p+1) points to.  The value at that index will not be changed, so the result of that code is to simply increment the pointer `p`.  This may or may not be what you want.  *Probably* not, but this can only be determined if you share with us how you have allocated and assigned the pointer `p` and the memory adjacent to it.

Comment: I'm sorry I edited your answer. I confused it with mine :) I didn't modify anything though. Sorry for the inconvenience :)

Answer (score 3):

It will increment the value of the array element indexed with `int(nintervals*number)` in memory. This is equivalent to

```
++( p[int(nintervals*number)] );  
 |  \_______________________/
 |             |
 |             V 
 |             Array element is evaluated first
 |
 V 
 then ++ operator increment that array element
```

Answer (score 1):

The precedence of the operators make that code equivalent to:

```
++(p[int(nintervals*number)]);
```

That is, the preincrement applies to the element at that position in the array, not the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

`++exp` increments the value of `exp` **before** being evaluated. It differs from `exp++` in that the later evaluates `exp` and is later incremented.

In your code, you're accessing an element in the array and incrementing it. It can be rewritten int two more ways:

```
p[int(nintervals*number)]++;
p[int(nintervals*number)] += 1;
```

To get a better feeling of the difference between postfix and prefix `++` operator, take a look at this code:

```
int a = 1;
if(a++ == 1){
    printf("yes");
}
else{
    printf("no");
}
```

This output will be "yes", as it will be the boolean expression will first be evaluated and later `a` will be incremented. On the other hand:

```
int a = 1;
if(++a == 1){
    printf("yes");
}
else{
    printf("no");
}
```

the output will be "no", since `a` will be first incremented and then the boolean expression will be evaluated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In this case `exp++` is same as `++exp`. No difference.

Comment: @haccks I noticed :) updated the answer for further explanation. Thanks!